# AJAX request not sending complete data in php page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have been trying to post a status in my web application through AJAX which is sending a request to a PHP page and PHP page processes information furthermore.

```
function Upload_Status(id){
  var description=$('#Txt-editor').val();
  var data="q="+description;
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', 'status.php', true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  xhr.onload = function () {
    var  response=this.responseText;
    if (!(response=="" || response==null)) {
      document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = response;
    }
  };
  xhr.send(data);
}
```

And *status.php* is

```
echo $_POST['q'];
```

which returns sometime half string and something quarter. I don't know what the problem is as I'm using a text editor, I also have changed editor but when this generates HTML code this creates the problem.

Any help?

Comment: Please change `xhr.onload` to  `xhr.onreadystatechange`

Comment: so is `status.php` simply `echo $_POST['q'];` and no more?

Comment: use jQuery ajax

Comment: @GufranHasan I have tried this also  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
           
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
              document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = this.responseText;
                 
           }};
but returning same problem.
Before getting response if i display result this returns complete html code in alert of javascript but after opening page of status.php this returns me half of string.

Comment: @RamRaider status page inserts data to mysql but i commented the complete code just to check what php page is getting in description and i'm displaying description in a div to check out the actual description received  in php page.

Comment: change `xhr.onload` to `xhr.onreadystatechange` and wait till `readyState` become `4`

Comment: Can you give me some hint with code please? how to change my code to this way? as i told you i have tried this out in if statement im doing the same thing if readyState becomes equal to 4 and status becomes equal to 200 that give response. so how you are saying to change it out?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the text you're submitting?

Comment: I can't see the check for status 200 and readyState 4 in your code

Comment: @LeonWillens i'm getting html code from the editor for example.
I have types ' Hey there Guys this is my first status' and i bolded this text so editor returns me the following code.
<p><b>Hey there Guys this is my first status</b></p>
This is what my editor returns and i stores in description.
Some time this gives me complete out put and some time this is broken before ending of tag means before </b>

Comment: @SagarV Please check my first comment as i have mentioned there that i have tried this out but again i'm having the same problem.

Comment: in php, Are you sure you need to echo instead of returning something?

Comment: @zetawars I'm testing it out basically im inserting data to mysql and returns 'Successfully uploaded' Message in that div, but my system is creating problem so thats why i'm testing this out if im entering plane text this works fine but when editor returns me some html code as i perform editor's operations then it creates this problem.

Comment: you can console.log() the response. what do you mean by half string? does it halves the html page? how are you generating the html response. Also please check if you are not parsing it into json or anything at return.

Comment: @zetawars this one i tried before getting response from the php page and after the PHP page.
Before readystatechange i loged description which is returning complete HTML code and after opening page i'm not having the same response.
which is the actual problem.

Comment: I have checked it out and found my error.

Comment: I'm sending data from editor that returns HTML code to my php page throught 'xhr.send(data);' due to huge amount of HTML code data is not send and system is returning 404 error. before error 'xhr.send(data);' sends some data to page and after that shows error so thats why half of string is recorded and other is not.

Comment: There you guys have any idea how to escape of it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this questions myself.
the problem was with the special symbols,commas and quotation signs etc. If i encrypt information sending from JS and decode JSON response and which return response from PHP i encode this response again to JSON, then this problem is solved :-)